# Losing space in TableLayout

Tags: android

I have something strange on a tableLayout.
In each `tablelayout`, I losing space at the bottom, as you can see on the  (I've highlighted it with yellow).

[image]

Anybody have an idea ?
I try to set some value like layout_height without success.

```
 <TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titreProgramme"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/descriptionProgramme"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/IconeProgramme"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

This tableLayout is in a LinearLayout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="top"

android:layoutDirection="ltr"
android:orientation="vertical">
```

To be easy, I don't want space after the last TableRow.

Comment: Add your xml code pls.

Comment: Post code......

Comment: Done. thx for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your table to wrap the content exactly just change

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
```

To

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
```

Comment: Oh, sure, you also need to change height for TableRow from `match_parent` to `wrap_content` or fixed value